# sentence meaning "may be just relaxation"

Tags: sentence-meaning

[**Sources**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Don%27t+forget+to+set+aside+enough+time+for+entertainment,+hobbies+,+and+maybe+just+relaxation.%22&num=50&filter=0&biw=1231&bih=1262)

**Be sure to set aside enough time for entertainment,hobbies, and may be just relaxation.**
I can't guess correctly what  the writer means "may be just relaxation."
It means

> "We must set aside eniugh time for all possible relaxation such as entertainment,hobbies etc--"
>                 (or)
>   We must set aside enough time but it may be as little as possible to relax.

Comment: I think *may be* is a typo for *maybe* = "perhaps".

Comment: @learner When you cite text from a page, why do you not copy and paste it instead of rephrasing it yourself and introducing typographical errors (as above)? Also, please always include a link to the source.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a typo.

Comment: I saw many questions that did not give the respective link on this page.

Comment: @Alan Carmack This sentence is from our English Text Book .So,I can neither provide the link nor know it is a typo.

Comment: @learner What is the title of the book? Who are the author and publisher?

Comment: The title is "How to improve your study habit".The autor and the publisher are not mentioned in the Text Book.

Comment: @learner A  _book_ is a specific thing. It is a physical object. It has pages, covers, and usually a table of contents. Any real book was written by someone, and is published by a publisher. How is this book distributed to students or teachers? If there is no publisher, from whom is the book purchased?

Comment: It is for students and our text book is edited by our educational resarchers.They are adapted from many articles and usually never described the name of the original writer and even title.It is one of  our difficulties.

Comment: The "educational researchers" are doing a disservice to the students. This particular sentence was merely copied, and inaccurately, from one of scores of websites which themselves appear to have been written by persons who  do not speak English.

Answer (score 1):

> Be sure to set aside enough time for entertainment, hobbies, and *maybe* just relaxation.

It means to set aside time for the conjoined items (entertainment, hobbies, and relaxation).

"just maybe" adds a bit of hesitancy for that item, meaning relaxation is important but you might consider it a bit more.